# SearchView in ActionBar for Maps onQueryTextSubmit

Tags: android, maps

I want to have a searchview in the actionbar that sets a marker on the map.

I've done it already with an edittext (with a tutorial from wptrafficanalyzer.in for the JSON stuff) but the searchview is more native but I don't get the result from the searchview to my location in onQueryTextSubmit. GetText doesn't work but getQuery want's to have a return false which results in a NullPointerException.

I hope anybody can help me :-)

Here's my code:

```
    // Getting reference to SearchView

    search=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);

    search.setOnQueryTextListener (new OnQueryTextListener() {
    // Setting click event listener for the find button


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
            // Getting the place entered
            String location = search.getText().toString();

            if(location==null || location.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";

            try {
                // encoding special characters like space in the user input place
                location = URLEncoder.encode(location, "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String address = "address=" + location;

            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // url , from where the geocoding data is fetched
            url = url + address + "&" + sensor;

            // Instantiating DownloadTask to get places from Google Geocoding service
            // in a non-ui thread
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading the geocoding places
            downloadTask.execute(url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by myself :-)

I had to put the SearchView query stuff to OnCreateOptionsMenu and put "query" as return value, so it is "String location = query;" for those who are interested

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you provided code. I am not clear what you did to fix the problem.